# Syncing Vagrant VMs across different physical servers

Tags: linux, vagrant, backup, virtual-machine, synchronization

I'm using Vagrant to deploy my VMs and my current setup looks like this:

```
server1 = VM1, VM2, VM3 ( main production server )
server2 = VM1, VM2, VM3 ( backup server )
```

My questions is, can I somehow sync the VMs across the different physical servers in case one fails so I can keep running the VMs on the second one without experiencing any downtime ?

I know there is the *Synced Folders* option within Vagrant but that is not what I need, I basically need to clone the VMs from server1 to server2 periodically in case of the downtime so they can keep on running on the backup server while the main one doesn't get up again.

Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vagrant doesn't inherently support this, since it's intended audience is really development environments. It seems like you're looking for something more like what [VMWare vSphere](http://www.vmware.com/products/vsphere/) does.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I'll definitely take a look at it. Thanks.